# How moving on to another ViewController when finished playing video?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How moving on to another ViewController when finished playing video? From '2' to '1' (look at screenshot)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVFlh.png]

Code in `viewDidLoad`(`videoViewControler`):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"_http://scontent-a.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t50.2886-16/10619021_616434485141882_380154097_n.mp4"];

videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

[videoPlayer.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[videoPlayer.moviePlayer play];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayer];    

NSArray *viewControllers = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:viewControllers[1] animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register for did finish notification, for example in viewDidLoad:

```
// Register for finished notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(moveToView2:)
    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
    object:self.moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer];
```

Add notification method and call segue to go to another view:

```
- (void) moveToView2:(NSNotification *) notification {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER" sender:self];
}
```

Just make sure to replace IDENTIFIER with the segue identifier between view A and B.

Answer (score 0):

Add an observer for MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification which will inform you when the movie has finished, then you can pop the view controller back.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(movieFinished:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:_moviePlayer];
```